# Help with question comparing logistic regression analyses

Tags: regression, logistic

I have accounted a problem when trying to finish my analyses. So, I want to compare the beta weights between two logistic regression analyses from independent samples (same IV and DV in both regression analyses). As far as I know, there are not any established tests to test the significance in differences between beta weights.
So I have standardized the beta weights and applied the method of comparing the confidence overlap described in the article of G. Cumming from 2009 (Inference by eye: reading the overlap of independent confidence intervals. Stat Med, 28(2), 205-220.).
My question: is it accurate to compare the beta weights from two logistic regression models in this way?
Appreciated if not trying to overcomplicate the answer. I do not want to be more confused.

Comment: What exactly is different about the beta weights you are mentioning? Does one model have more predictors than another?

Comment: there is nothing different about the models. They have the same predictors.

Comment: How are the beta weights different then? I think there is something missing in your question.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand I think the OP has two distinct samples so the coefficients could differ.

Answer (score 3):

Confidence interval overlap is never appropriate, as this disagrees with what you get when you compute the proper confidence limits for *differences*.  Your problem is appropriately and easily addressed by combining the two samples, having an indicator variable say $s$ for which sample an observation comes from, and later interacting $s$ with all the model variables.  Suppose there are $p$ model variables and after expanding them to include originally specified nonlinearities and interactions among the Xs there are $q$ ($q \geq p)$ parameters.  Get the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test statistic for all $q + 1$ parameters, with $q + 1$ degrees of freedom.  Now add all $q$ interaction terms between predictor terms and $s$ and compute the model likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ with $q + 1 + q$ degrees of freedom.  Subtract the two $\chi^2$ to get a $q$ degree of freedom test statistic for interaction.  This tests whether any of the $q$ coefficients differ between the first and second samples.  It contains a perfect multiplicity adjustment.

Comment: Thank you Frank for your answer! I have no knowledge how to go about and test this in SPSS. Do you have any recommendations of SPSS instructions?

Comment: The hard part in SPSS is probably how to relax linearity assumptions on the predictors.  But the rest of what I mentioned above should be in the standard output, as I think that virtual all stat packages compute the LR test.  This is very easy to do in R.